# How do I file feature request bugs on Launchpad?

Tags: launchpad, bug-reporting

I've seen on Bugzilla bug request for enhancements, is there anything similar for Launchpad?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what kind of feature request you have in mind.

Comment: @poolie, I believe that'd make the question too specific. I wanted to know the general procedure to file a feature request on Launchpad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can file a bug for small issues but a member of the QA team will have to set the importance to 'wishlist'.

For bigger features, if you have the expertise and time to write a blueprint then you should enter it on https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ You should make sure that you can fill it out in enough detail for a developer to start work, and also the perseverance to bring it to the attention of someone to do the work if you can't do it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ is meant for feature requests.</strike>

closed as of today

Comment: A good explanation can be found [here](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.martin-graesslin.com%2Fblog%2F2011%2F05%2Fdie-bugtracker-luge%2F)

Comment: Brainstorm? That's one of the most useless component of the community. But I get the problem with bug as feature requests. Is there no feature request category?

Answer (score 1):

You can file a bug, but it's worth pausing before you do file to consider whether filing is going to help improve Ubuntu.  The goal is to get a great operating system, not to build a kind of encyclopedia of every idea that could possibly be implemented.

So, an improvement is only actually useful if it is implemented and shipped.  There are basically two paths towards that: implement it yourself (or with a friend), or persuade the existing developers to implement it.

Implementing it yourself is a much more sure way to get something done - anywhere in life, but especially in free software.  If it's a very large feature and you've never touched the code before it may be hard.  A good general way to start is to at least get your toe in the water by fixing some easy bugs in the project and then talk to the developers about the thing you really want to build.

If you want other people to implement your idea, you need to work whether this is really more important than other things they might be doing now, and how to convince them to do it.  Generally speaking just a bug suggesting an idea is not very persuasive: projects already have a lot of bugs, and they also have a lot of ideas about what to do next.  It depends a bit on what the particular feature is.  One thing you can do is make a blog post with mockups showing how it could work.

So, in short, if you want a particular feature, in any free software project:

1. write it yourself, or
2. at least show a lot of willingness to write it if someone will help you get started, or
3. put up a blog post that's really persuasive about how incredibly cool and exciting the feature will be

Comment: Though I don't believe it's got anything to do with feature requests on Launchpad, it's a good post. The blog post part, specially, has been on my mind. It'll be worth becoming an Ubuntu Member and posting on Planet Ubuntu for more readers.

Comment: Well, the answer I'm proposing to "how do I file feature requests on Launchpad" is, basically, "thoughtfully", or even "don't".  That's much more important than how you do it technically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/launchpad) for that.

Here are a few samples of feature request: [feature requests on launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+questions?field.sort=by%20relevancy&field.language-empty-marker=1&field.actions.search=Search&field.status=Open&field.status=Needs%20information&field.status=Answered&field.status=Solved&field.search_text=Feature%20request)

Comment: Actually those are mostly questions, not feature requests, including questions similar to this one.

Comment: Feature request are often a bug of something not working as expected ;)